# Should I use the same Google Analytics code for my website and native mobile app?

Tags: google-analytics

My website is a forum. The native mobile app's only function is to access the forum and provide a better experience than can be provided through the browser.

Given that the same content is being accessed, should I use the same Google Analytics tracking code?

Or should I create a new property and select "Not a website" when it asks for the website?
[image: Google Analytics selecting Not a Website]

I was not able to find anything that discussed this and what would be best practice, given that the same content is being accessed.

Thanks!

Comment: If its the same content being accessed keep the same Analytics profile so you can create reports to see how visitor browse your site, as well as monitor revenue if you integrate with AdSense.

Answer (score 1):

If the native app is using a webpage view to access the site, use the same Google Analytics tracking code.

Comment: This will not work as the session within the webview will be recognised as a different session from the native app session.

Answer (score 1):

Its entirely up to you. It might be helpful to see the specific path your mobile users take and compare it to your desktop users. EX: if the platforms have different use patterns, you could adjust the interface on your mobile or desktop experience to reflect those specific users needs.

Answer (score 1):

the code simply allows you to track the visits to your site. Google allows for as many sites as you want. For some, they do not need the level of detail achieved through tracking the mobile users apart from the desktop site. But you might find interesting information by analyzing the data differentials between mobile users, desktop users, content visited, and referring information. Thus, depending on your situation, and your desired information resolution, you choose whether or not to use separate code for desktop vs. mobile app.